# A parameterized helper class, calling from cshtml page returns value, c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

lets assume "Index.cshtml" page.
In this page, I want to call a 'Test' Class passing some parameter that returns string value.

for ex,

```html
<div>
  <p>@Test("parameter")</p>
</div>
```

i want a Test(string parameter) class that returns string.
ex,

```html
public class Test
{
  public string Test(string value)
  {
    return "success";
  }
}
```

In a result, Index page renders "success".

I am trying to follow the technique used by NopCommerce for localization.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't know if I am missing something, but this can be achieved using a simple model/viewmodel.

Comment: You would have to create a custom `WebViewPageBase`. See http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/21/changing-base-type-of-a-razor-view.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code:

1. The same name for class and method (`Test`)
2. There is no instance of the class on which to call the method.

So, the following should work:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static string Test(string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
}

<div>
    <p>@TestClass.Test(value)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment... but I am looking for the way of like  @TestClass(value) instead of @TestClass.Test(value)....